# How is the UIView integration with Core Animation? Layer hosting or layer-backed views?

Tags: iphone, uikit, core-animation

I am not very sure, but I would bet on layer-backed views. That is:

> Layer-backed views use Core Animation
>   layers as their backing store,freeing
>   the views from the responsibility of
>   refreshing the screen. The views need
>   to redraw only when the view content
>   actually changes.

Or is it the other method of integration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All iPhone views are layer-backed.

Comment: This is the default, but you can make UIViews host a custom CALayer subclass by overriding the +layerClass class method.  An example of this would be OpenGL-displaying views that use CAEAGLLayer as their hosted layer.